# React Router Match Path issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux-form

React router `matchPath` issue.

I have a url: `/users/test?dp=1` and path as `/users/:id`

When we pass to `matchpath` of `react-router` the `:id` gives `test?dp=1`.
I only want `test` as the output. I do not want to change the `url`.

```js
const match = matchPath("/users/test?dp=1", {
  path: "/users/:id",
  exact: true,
  strict: false
});
console.log(match);
```

Comment: can you show your route configuration?, you might only need to add the exact prop like so `<Route path="/users/test" exact />`

Comment: const match = matchPath("/users/test?dp=1", {
  path: "/users/:id",
  exact: true,
  strict: false
});
console.log(match);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@GauthamShetty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6819576/gautham-shetty),

Here is the reference on [`matchPath`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/matchPath.md).

What you'll want to do is use `req.path` rather than `req.url`, which includes the query string part of the URL. `matchPath` is meant to receive only the `path` without a query string.

You can see mention of that here:
[matchPath not working with queryParams in url #5285](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5285)